# how can I prove properties of these norms

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

how can I prove that (1) $||x + y|| \geq |\ ||x|| - ||y||\ | $ and 
(2) $$ || \sum_{i=1}^n\ x^{(i)}|| \le \sum_{i=1}^n\ ||x^{(i)}|| $$ for vectors $x^1,\cdots, x^n$

I know that I am supposed to somehow use the triangle inequality I am just unsure how.

Answer (score 4):

We have by triangle inequality
$$||x||=||(x+y)-y||\leq||x+y||+||y||$$
so $$||x||-||y||\leq||x+y||\tag{1}$$
now switch $x$ and $y$ we find
$$||y||-||x||\leq||x+y||\tag{2}$$
so $(1)+(2)$ gives
$$\left|||x||-||y||\right|\leq||x+y||$$

Finally prove the second inequality by induction using the triangle inequality.